# When does C not need the address-of operator?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, reference, upcasting

In C are there any times other than for arrays that the address-of operator is not needed? For example, I know this code needs the address of operator:

```
typedef struct foo_t {
    int bar;
} foo_t;

void foo_init(foo_t *f) { f->bar = 123; }

... {
    foo_t f;

    foo_init(&f);
}
```

But this code will not need the address-of operator:

```
... {
    char buffer[1024];
    memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
}
```

Here `memset` is declared as:

```
void *memset(void *ptr, int value, size_t num);
```

And in C it will auto cast that `char[]` to a `void*` - but trying to do the same for the `foo_t` like this:

```
 foo_t f;
 memset(f, 0, sizeof(foo_t));
```

Won't work and will generate the expected compile-time type error. Like with the `char[]` example if we use an array it will work:

```
foo_t list[16];
memset(foo, 0, sizeof(list));
```

It will again automatically cast the `foo_t[]` into a `void*`

Is this the only time this kind of cast will happen in C? How can I know when these casts will happen?

Comment: The only other implicit “address taking operation” is for function names to function pointers.

Comment: @5gon12eder Please add that as an answer.

Comment: Any references would be great too. The C specs I can find aren't exactly *light* reading material.

Comment: Also guys I put this question here because I can't find the answer here on stackoverflow.com and thought the question would have been asked. If anyone can find a similar question that answers this that would be excellent.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I thought this might not be worth an answer but thanks to your motivation, it now is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only “other” (see comments) case of implicit address taking I know is with function pointers [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)].  Given a function

```
int
f(void);
```

the following two lines have identical meaning.

```
int (*fptr1)(void) = f;
int (*fptr2)(void) = &f;
```

Both make `fptr1` and `fptr2` a function pointer to `f` respectively.

Comment: I would say this is *the only case*. With arrays it's not true that you "don't need" the `&` operator. Rather, use or non-use of the `&` operator give seriously different results. `arrayname` by itself is equivalent to `&arrayname[0]`, not `&arrayname`.

Comment: @R.. Indeed.  That's also why I have used the weasel wording “implicit address taking” instead of “decay” because it is not the same that is going on here.  I have also put the “other” in quotes now.

Answer (score 1):

In this expression

```
char buffer[1024];
memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
```

the array decays to a pointer when passed to `memset`, `memset` expects a pointer to writable memory in it's first parameter.

This function

```
void foo_init(foo_t *f) 
{ 
    f->bar = 123; 
}
```

could also be written as

```
void foo_init(foo_t f) 
{ 
    f.bar = 123; 
}
```

but the passed parameter would be a copy of the original one and the changes would apply to the local copy only.

In the pointer version, the parameter points to the place where the struct is stored in memory and hence the changes are performed directly on to the same data that the **pointer** points to.

So you don't need to take the address of an array, because it's automaticaly decayed to a pointer that points to it's first element, when used as such, whereas when you pass an object allocated on the stack and you want to change it in the reciever function, you need to pass a pointer to it, for which you use the address of operator.

Comment: Thanks @iharob, I think I understand that in the question. My concern is when is this implicit casting going to happen in C otherwise. I'm mainly looking for where in the C spec (of any fashion) that it outlines this behavior so I can understand what else it may apply to.

Answer (score 1):

String literals are assigned by address to pointers, and by "value" when used as the rhs of an initialization:

```
const char *str_ptr = "foo";  /* str_ptr points to a string "foo",
                                 in read-only memory. */

char chr_ar[] = "barbar";     /* chr_ar is 7 bytes, and is initialized
                                 with the bytes "barbar" */
```